# Should I convert my Access 2002-2003 MDB to 2010 ACCDB?

Tags: ms-access

I has a headache, my question is not pure programming question, I don't know is it belong to the Stackoverflow question. Or it belong to somewhere else such as SuperUser?

**Current System :**

Currently, we are using Windows XP + Access 2003, we have a database system written in Access 2003 MDB format, it separtated into 2 MDB files, one for database data, and one for front-end.

Lucky, The front-end do not contain Data Access Page. It contains:

Forms, Reports, Queries, Macros, VBA Modules.

We have not use any third party objects, all forms/report only use the default Microsoft controls, all VBA only use the default Microsoft libraries.

**My headache background :**

Due to the policy of my company computer support department, force all of our computer workstation to upgrade from Windows XP + Office 2003 to Windows 7 + Office 2010, they force us to upgrade because they will not support **old system**.

My headache :

Now I study what should I do if my system will be Windows 7 + Access 2010. I have study something by Google. Here is my summary so far:

**Solution 1 : Convert the front-end MDB to ACCDB, keep the back-end MDB.**

Since back-end data is important, I don't want to take risk to do conversion. I am very concern will the front-end converion safe and easy? and can I link the ACCDB to MDB(password protected)?

**Solution 2 : Convert both 2 MDB to ACCDB.**

Will it easy and data safe? I worry it will crash my data.

**Solution 3 : Keep both 2 MDB remain MDB**

I read from Microsoft site, 97 MDB cannot change design, ok my system is 2003 MDB, but I very doubtful on 2003 MDB will have problems too. Access 2010 introduce many new objects, on the others hand, maybe some 2003 objects is no longer work in 2010. I have read from Google, some people cannot save the form/report design in MDB, because 2010 silently add the new objects.

Would anyone give me suggestion and share experience?

Comment: Why not make a copy of the two mdb's and try it?

Comment: Because, at this moment, the computer support department has not provide me the new Workstation to try and test yet. All I have to do is do some research and planning now. I have to plan it very early, because at the worst case, we have to re-write the whole system in ACCESS 2010 or by other front-end tech such as web, dot net...whatever...., and our big problem is. This system was build many years ago, the original developer have ZERO documentation, the system is very large and very complex now, hundred of forms/reports and thousand of queries which nest query by query many levels. Terrible.

Comment: You could plan all you liked but the most reliable way to tell if it will work for you is to just have a go then test everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the option to keep your database in mdb and run it in Access 2010. In 80% of the cases it will run well with any change. If you have issues, there is a page:

http://allenbrowne.com/Access2007.html

and also a utility tool to test your database:

http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html

Take a look at both and you will see how you can solve your dilemma.